# Suppress "localhost wants to access connected printers Untrusted Website" when accessing Printers - QZ-tray

Tags: javascript, printing, qz-tray

How to properly Suppress the

> localhost wants to access connected printers Untrusted Website

modal when accessing printers?

I've tried to create a certificate through this OpenSSL command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
```

Then addeed the override like this:

```
authcert.override=server.crt
```

in the `qz-tray.properties` file.

However it is still the same the dialog box is not suppressed. What could be wrong?

This is the complete cert properties file:

```
authcert.override=C:\\Program Files\\QZ Tray\\auth\\server.crt
wss.alias=qz-tray
wss.keypass=keypass
wss.storepass=storepass
wss.host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: @qz-support can you help check this one? Thanks!

Comment: There's a signing step, outlined in several different server languages available from the wiki/resources folder. Which server-side language are you using?

Comment: @QZSupport We will be deploying the web app with Electron(http://electron.atom.io/)  which will be totally localhost

Comment: I mean the web app will be for a physical Kiosk

Comment: We also have tried this: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/05/generating-valid-self-signed-certificates.html

Still getting the Allow popup

Comment: For offline or pure client-side signing, this will do it:. https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/assets/signing/sign-message.js

Comment: The salesforce article will work fundamentally for generating any old certificate and private key, but you should use 2048 for complexity.

Comment: @QZSupport if we purchase the license or support from your website will it help? We just want to take this "Allow" thing away without any hassle.

Comment: yes, the support package comes with a 1 year certificate -- that doesn't require any custom `properties` or command line shims -- as well as remote help for configuring it in your environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `qz-tray.properties` override will be introduced with version `2.0.2` and at the time of writing this, [`2.0.1` is the latest stable release](https://github.com/qzind/tray/releases).

Possible options:

- Wait for `2.0.2` / [compile from source](https://qz.io/wiki/Compiling) and use the `qz-tray.properties` override value

  - -- OR --
- Wait for `2.0.2` / [compile from source](https://qz.io/wiki/Compiling) but provide the certificate at packaging time, which will allow the `override.crt` to be distributed directly with the installer.

  ```
  ant nsis -Dauthcert.use=override.crt
  ```

  - -- OR --
- Use `2.0.1` and start the software with the certificate override via command line.  e.g:

  ```
  java -DtrustedRootCert=override.crt -jar qz-tray.jar
  ```

Since the latter option requires modification of the QZ Tray desktop launcher, this will ultimately lead to non-obvious issues when auto-start is enabled (e.g. auto-start on Windows is triggered by qz-tray.exe which will launch without the `-DtrustedRootCert` parameter).

This is why the `2.0.2` feature of providing the certificate permanently in `qz-tray.properties` is much preferred.  Note, compiling the latest QZ Tray is a [few quick steps](https://qz.io/wiki/Compiling).

But this is only half of the battle.  To suppress the security warnings, each message must be digitally signed. This is where the `server.key` comes into play.  We call this `private-key.pem` in our examples.

Signing is generally done server-side although [can be done client-side](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/assets/signing/sign-message.js) with [risk of key leakage](https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/issues/99#issuecomment-162090871).  This process is explained best in [the sign-messages wiki](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-signing-messages).

**Signing Messages**

- Signing uses the private key to create an [SHA1 signature](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) (which is appended to the JSON message to QZ Tray).
- In 1.9, the signature was based on the message contents, but 2.0 switched to [hashing the message first](https://qz.io/wiki/2.0-api-overrides#override-sha256) for performance and compatibility reasons.
- If the signature provided [validates against the certificate/chain](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/src/qz/auth/Certificate.java#L255:L279) and hasn't [reached a timeout](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/src/qz/common/Constants.java#L46), and the certificate isn't revoked and isn't expired, the security warning goes away.

**PHP Signing Example:**

```
<? // sign-message.php

$KEY = 'private-key.pem'; // or 'server.key', etc
$req = $_GET['request'];  // i.e. 'toSign' from JS
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents($KEY));
$signature = null;
openssl_sign($req, $signature, $privateKey);
if ($signature) {
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    echo base64_encode($signature);
    exit(0);
}
echo '<h1>Error signing message</h1>';
exit(1);

?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
qz.security.setSignaturePromise(function(toSign) {
    return function(resolve, reject) {
       $.ajax("/foo/bar/sign-message.php?request=" + toSign).then(resolve, reject);
    };
});

qz.security.setCertificatePromise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax("/foo/bar/digital-certificate.txt").then(resolve, reject); // or `server.crt`, etc
});
```

Note: To prevent key leakage, the private key should always be kept in a directory inaccessible by a web browser.

Comment: What is the purpose of signing in qz tray, can it be disabled?. Is it not sufficient to have CORS settings on qz tray side?

Comment: `What is the purpose of signing in qz tray` This may be better for its own question, but it's to verify the website is who it says it is, which is tricky to do securely in JavaScript. `can it be disabled` yes, but you have to recompile (which is trivial).   `Is it not sufficient to have CORS settings on qz tray side?` From a security perspective, that would probably suffice, but then each install would require special configuration.

Answer (score 7):

## Just suppress warning

If you're using QZ Tray in an isolated machine (like in my case), local environment or for any reason you don't need to encrypt messages and just wanna get rid of the warning message you can disable the warning dialog itself.

*Disclaimer: This method is not supposed to be used in production, messages won't be signed, any website can talk to your hardware, use under your own risk.*

1. Clone the QZ Tray repository ( https://github.com/qzind/tray.git ).
2. Fulfill the compiling dependencies: Ant, Java, NSIS (Windows).
   If you're using windows I recommend you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), with Chocolatey it's straightforward to install those dependencies.
3. Get a code editor or IDE (I used IntelliJ Idea community edition).
4. Navigate and edit 
   [`/src/qz/ws/PrintSocketClient.java`](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/6a3d0cc2fd4708b04eb92cba38f3bb35f93861bf/src/qz/ws/PrintSocketClient.java#L476) change line `476`

   From this:

   ```java
   if (cert.isTrusted() && cert.isSaved()) {
   ```

   into

   ```java
   if (cert.isSaved()) {
   ```
5. Navigate and edit [`/src/qz/ui/GatewayDialog.java`](https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/6a3d0cc2fd4708b04eb92cba38f3bb35f93861bf/src/qz/ui/GatewayDialog.java#L92) change line `92`

   From

   ```java
   allowButton.setEnabled(!persistentCheckBox.isSelected() || cert.isTrusted());
   ```

   into

   ```java
   allowButton.setEnabled(true);
   ```
6. Compile using:

   - `ant nsis` for windows
   - `ant pkgbuild` for MacOS
   - `ant makeself` for linux

   Actually this won't only compile but also creates the installer. QZ team did a great job automatizing everything.
7. Install QZ tray using the installer just created.
8. The first time you'll see the warning but now you can `Remember` the decision to `Allow` forever.

*I suggest to use self-signed certificates or pay premium support if you need a truly secure setup.*

Comment: Bypassing the dialogs gives all webpages access to USB ports, serial ports, printers, and in some cases the local filesystem.  Self-signed instances are the most secure (more-so than the paid certificates) because only those with access to the private key will ever show as "Trusted" .  Advising code modifications over the accepted answer is a very dangerous proposition, as any unsuspecting site can just talk to one's hardware.  It should be against most basic ethical standards to propose this without a very, very strong warning.

Comment: "messages won't be encrypted" is misleading.  "messages won't be signed" is correct, but a consumer won't know what that means.  "Any website can talk to your hardware" is most accurate.  Regarding encryption: HTTPS will encrypt the transport 
 for HTTPS pages.  QZ Tray doesn't do any further encryption, it's all on the transport layer.  Instead, SHA1 digital signatures are used for validation.  Removing this validation means any website can talk to your hardware without your knowledge, which should be terrifying to any IT professional.

Comment: @tresf you're right, I edited this answer with your warnings and corrections.

Comment: Thanks, however the recommendations for premium support are not needed.  Self-signed certificates are arguably most secure so it would be most accurate (as well as less soliciting) to leave out any specificities involving payment.

Comment: @tresf thanks to you. I modified that suggestion. I still think that paying support is actually advisable in my experience but also to use a self-signed certificate is so I suggest both.

Answer (score 1):

For localhost use, if you are not lucky dealing with the certificate's stuff, you can modify the source code before compiling it.

(Updated solution, based on ZooMMX's answer)

For example: To bypass the certificate validation modify the return of the function "certificate.isSignatureValid" (change it to always return "true")

Version 2.2.4

1. File 1: /src/qz/ui/GatewayDialog.java

1.1

```
persistentCheckBox = new JCheckBox(Constants.REMEMBER_THIS_DECISION, false); // Comment it
persistentCheckBox = new JCheckBox(Constants.REMEMBER_THIS_DECISION, true);   // Add this line
```

1.2

```
persistentCheckBox.addActionListener(e -> allowButton.setEnabled(!persistentCheckBox.isSelected() || request.isVerified())); // comment it
persistentCheckBox.addActionListener(e -> allowButton.setEnabled(true));   // Add
```

2. File 2:  /src/qz/ws/PrintSocketClient.java

```
// Find this function...

private boolean validSignature(Certificate certificate, JSONObject message) throws JSONException {
    ...
     

    return certificate.isSignatureValid(Certificate.Algorithm.valueOf(algorithm), signature, copy.toString().replaceAll("\\\\/", "/"));  // comment it 
    return true;  // Add this line
}

// Now you can use any pair of certificates, don't worry about missmatch.
```

Comment: Please make sure to properly format your code and remove unnecessary code and comments